# Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled in .larave 7?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-echo

i am  trying to create **Presence Channels** for *chat group*, i setup *redis* and every thing is required but this error appear however i Run

> composer require predis/predis

and using * laravel echo sever* .
i create event to listen chat app and this code
message event :

```
class Message implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $message;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct( \App\Message $message)
{
     $this->message=$message;
     //dd();
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('chat-group');
}
}
```

Message Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $m=new Message();
    $m->content=$request->message;
    $m->user_id=Auth::id();
    $m->save();
    broadcast(new \App\Events\Message($m))->toOthers();
}
```

App js:

```
window.Echo.channel('chat-group')
.listen('Message', (e) => {
    console.log(e.message.content);
});
```

> D:\work\chat>redis-cli ping
> PONG
> result:

```
{
"message": "Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.",
"exception": "LogicException",
"file": 
]
}
```

env :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

laravel echo sever :

```
 L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

 version 1.6.2

 ⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

  ✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
  ✔  Channels are ready.
  ✔  Listening for http events...
  ✔  Listening for redis events...

  Server ready!

  [1:04:07 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost:8000
  [1:04:07 PM] - Sending auth request to: http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth

  [1:04:07 PM] - fZvJEifYevcj805nAAAA joined channel: chat-group
   [1:04:07 PM] - fZvJEifYevcj805nAAAA authenticated for: presence-online
  [1:04:07 PM] - fZvJEifYevcj805nAAAA joined channel: presence-online
  [1:04:08 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://localhost:8000
  [1:04:08 PM] - Sending auth request to: http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth

  [1:04:08 PM] - kif6o7whupgU9GH2AAAB joined channel: chat-group
  [1:04:08 PM] - kif6o7whupgU9GH2AAAB authenticated for: presence-online
  [1:04:08 PM] - kif6o7whupgU9GH2AAAB joined channel: presence-online
```

Comment: What more can we say than to install and enable the PHP Redis extension?! Installing Redis alone won't do it. If you already installed the PHP Redis extension edit your `php.ini` file and enable it. Maybe restart your webserver

Comment: ok its work i just add extension to php.ini